# How to check if a scala Option type is None in Java code

Tags: java, scala

I have Scala class that will generate an `Option[StructType]` value which will be used in a Java function. In that java function, I need to check if this `Option[StructType]` is Scala `None` or not. How do I do that?

#### Scala class:

```
class Person(columns : String) {
    val recordStruct : Option[StructType] = {
        if ( columns != null && !columns.isEmpty()) {
          Some(new StructType(fields.map(field => 
                              StructField(field, StringType, true)).toArray))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }   
}
```

#### Java function:

```
StructType structure =  person.recordStruct().get();

// how to check if structure is None (in scala) ????

if (structure is None) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `if(!structure.isDefined())` would tell you if `structure` is `None`.  Except that `structure` isn't really an `Option`. `person.recordStruct()` is.

Comment: I don't see structType has a isDefined() function.

Comment: that's because `structType` isn't an `Option` (it's a `StructType`, duh). See my updated comment above.

Comment: You can just do `StructType structure =  person.recordStruct().orNull()` if you prefer

Comment: so I should use person.recordStruct().isDefined(), not structure.isDefined() ?

Comment: Yes. `person.recordStruct()` returns an `Option`. `Option.get()` returns (in this case) a `StructType`. You can use `isDefined` (or `isEmpty`) on the `Option` to see if it is (or not) defined BEFORE you do `get` (it'll throw if option was `None`). Or you can just use `orNull` on the `Option`: it'll give you the `StructType` if the option was defined or `null` otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Option<StructType> maybeStructure = person.recordStruct();
if (maybeStructure.isEmpty()) { 
    // do something if None
} else {
    StructType structure =  person.recordStruct().get();
    // now you can use structure...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  By looking at them, it seems I can use either isDefined() or isEmpty() on Option type.

Comment: Correct - of course `o.isDefined() == !o.isEmpty()`.